# Add new subroutine using IDA for ARM binary

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm, ios, function-hooking

I am trying to recreate a patch for an ARM binary. As it shows in attached picture, I have provided the before and after sections of file. In patched file, a new subroutine is added in a cave, and then it branches to an existing subroutine that has changed to an instruction.

My question is, how do you recreate such a patch? I know how to edit bytes in IDA, but not sure how to add new ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is done first by determining a code cave. Afterwards, just patch the binary using an application like Hex Fiend. The rest will show in IDA

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the task you're looking for using either one of the following approaches:

- Use the built-in IDA feature to assemble instructions and patch the binary available by accessing `Edit > Patch Program > Assembly` after highlighting the instruction you want to replace
- Use [Keypatch](http://www.keystone-engine.org/keypatch/) as it adds support for more architectures than what IDA provides by default